# How to redirect controller to razor page in area section asp Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

I want to redirect from my controller to a razor page that's in an area section. My controller user is restricted if the user is null then redirects to the login page in `Area/Identity/Pages/Account/login.cshtml`.

My Controller:

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            if (user == null)
            {
                //return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");

                return RedirectToPage("Login");
            }
```

How do I write a return line to redirect to my login page using `asp.net core 2.1`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use this line to redirect to page from controller action

```
return LocalRedirect("/Identity/Account/Login");
```

Comment: if you want to redirect to specific url after login add ?ReturnUrl=%2Fdashboard
, in this example it should redirect to dashboard after login.

Comment: How about in combination with `.UsePathBase("/app")`?

Answer (score 10):

This works too:

```
return RedirectToPage("/Account/Login", new { area = "Identity" });
```

tested in asp.net core 2.2

Comment: I'm implementing a redirect within an OnAuthorization filter.  While inside a controller, when I have to use `RedirectToPageResult` I get the error `The relative page path 'ChangePassword' can only be used while executing a Razor Page. Specify a root relative path with a leading '/' to generate a URL outside of a Razor Page`

Answer (score 3):

Use below code, want redirect **from Razor View**::

```
<a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code if you have any route values

```
return RedirectToPage("/Account/Login", new { area = "Identity",returnUrl = TempData["ReturnUrl"].ToString() });
```